# Iterate through an object containing list of objects in Terraform

Tags: terraform

This is my variable definition:

```
variable "assets" {
  type = map(object({
    car = object({
      name = string
      tires = list(string)
    })

    house = object({
      rooms = list(object({
        name = string
        furnitures = list(string)
      }))
    })
}
```

If I have this input:

```
assets {
  car = {
    name = "bmw"
    tires = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
  }

  house = {
        rooms = [
          {
            name = "living_room"
            furnitures = ["chair, table"]
          },
          {
            name = "bed_room"
            furnitures = ["bed, pillow"]
          }
        ]
   }
}
```

In the resource I've iterated through the asset value:

```
resource "test" "test" {
  for_each = {
    for asset in assets : asset.key => asset
  }
}
```

I want to extract the object contains list of objects (**each.value.house.rooms**) to two list like below (in the resource):

```
room_names = ["living_room", "bed_room"]
room_furnitures = [["chair","table"], ["bed", "pillow"]]
```

The pseudo-code that I can think of should be:

```
room_names = for room in each.value.house.rooms: room.name
room_furnitures = for room in each.value.house.rooms: room.furnitures
```

Comment: Would the resulting `map(list(string))` involve a single `asset`, or aggregate multiple `assets`? Based on the type specification, I would have to assume a single `house` per `asset`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I correctly understand the issue, but you can get your two lists as follows:

```
variable "house" {

  default = {
        rooms = [
          {
            name = "living_room"
            furnitures = ["chair, table"]
          },
          {
            name = "bed_room"
            furnitures = ["bed, pillow"]
          }
        ]
   }

}


locals {
  room_names = [for room in var.house.rooms : room["name"]]
  room_furnitures = [for room in var.house.rooms : room["furnitures"]]
}

output "room_names" {
  value = local.room_names
}

output "room_furnitures" {
  value = local.room_furnitures
}
```

The output is:

```
oom_furnitures = [
  [
    "chair, table",
  ],
  [
    "bed, pillow",
  ],
]
room_names = [
  "living_room",
  "bed_room",
]
```

#### In resource example

```
resource "test" "test" {
  for_each = {for idx, room in local.room_names : idx => room }

}
```

Comment: Yeah the output is what I need. But can we have that in resource (instead of output)?

Comment: @highDopamine I added new example. You can check it if you can

Comment: Because I have used the for_each value for iterating through the "assets" variable. So I cannot do that. You can see the way I iterate through the "assets" variable in my question. My question is that after I iterate through "assets" variable in resource. How can I iterate through each.value.house.rooms?

Comment: @highDopamine Sadly I don't know what is `assets`. You haven't provided any example of assets variable. The only thing you listed is `house`.

Comment: You can see my first block of code, there is a variable "assets" that wrap around the "house"

Comment: Can you provide an actuall example of `variable "asset"` so that I can copy and paste it instead of `variable "house"`?